# how to make a thread wait and notify in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Imagine that a Master is asking 5 Guides to help 5 kids print a document which has n number of lines. There is only one printer in the school. Now the kid with lines more than 100 should wait before other kids finish printing. I have written the following code

```
public enum Printer {

printer;

public synchronized void print(Kid kid) {
    if(kid.getPagesToPrint()<100){
        System.out.println(kid.getName()+" is printing "+kid.getPagesToPrint()+" pages");
        notify();
    }else{
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

The kid class

```
 public class Kid {

private String name;

private int pagesToPrint;

public Kid(String name, int pagesToPrint) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.pagesToPrint = pagesToPrint;
}

public int getPagesToPrint() {
    return pagesToPrint;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setPagesToPrint(int pagesToPrint) {
    this.pagesToPrint = pagesToPrint;
}
```

}

The GuideThread class

```
 public class GuideThread implements Runnable {

private Kid kid;

public GuideThread(Kid kid) {
    super();
    this.kid = kid;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Printer.printer.print(kid);
}
```

}

And finally the Master Class
      public class Master {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=1;i<6;i++){
        Thread t = new Thread(new GuideThread(new Kid("Kid_"+i,i*23)));
        t.start();
    }
}
```

}

When i execute it , the program is waiting for a few minutes and then terminates.Can someone correct this code so that the threads which are waiting
are notified and then printed after all less no.of.pages are printed first.

Comment: The output is as follows Kid_3 is printing 69 pages
Kid_2 is printing 46 pages
Kid_1 is printing 23 pages
Kid_4 is printing 92 pages

Comment: Your waiting condition is wrong: the kid with more than 100 pages should only wait if another kid has less than 100. Otherwise, the kid will wait forever. Also, wait( should always be inside a loop. In your code, if a kid waits and is notified, it doesn't end up printing: the print() method just returns after the wait. wait() and notify() are way too low level. You should use a PriorityBlockingQueue here to print the small documents first, and the long one last.

Comment: Is this possible only by using a PriorityBlockingQueue..Can't we do it using just wait/notify/notifyAll methods?

Answer (score 1):

Here :

```
for(int i=1;i<6;i++){
    Thread t = new Thread(new GuideThread(new Kid("Kid_"+i,i*23)));
    t.start();
}
```

The last thread to be run is the Thread with more 100 pages to print.
As the processing performed by each thread is very short, each run thread very probably finishes its execution before the next thread starts its execution.

If you want that the kid that has the maximum of pages to print be run in the first threads, make it start as the first one.

Your second problem is here :

```
public synchronized void print(Kid kid) {
    if(kid.getPagesToPrint()<100){
        System.out.println(kid.getName()+" is printing "+kid.getPagesToPrint()+" pages");
        notify();
    }else{
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`if (kid.getPagesToPrint()>=100),` the kid has to wait for.
But if no kids notify him because all kids have already finished their printing, the last kid is stuck.

So, `if(kid.getPagesToPrint()<100)` is clearly not enough to decide whether the kind can print.
You should consider the presence of waiting for kids in this condition.

It looks like a homework. I think that it is enough to guide you.

Comment: You should consider the presence of waiting for kids in this condition -  can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit different approach would be using a `PriorityBlockingQueue` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html.

What you could do is :

1. Create `PriorityBlockingQueue` with a `Comparator` which compares `Kids` using the number of pages to print.
2. Implement the `Printer` class to poll the `PriorityBlockingQueue` for new items.
3. Implement `GuideThread` to feed the `PriorityBlockingQueue` with `Kids` and start the `Printer`
4. This approach also allows continuous feeding of the `Kids` which will be compared and prioritized with the other `Kids`in the queue based on the number of pages to print.
5. It also allows to clearly separate 3 aspects of a program : Producing, Consuming, Prioritization, allowing them to evolve separately.

Hope this helps.